# why wireshark show total ip length as "0"?

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

i'm develping a tool that can analyzer ip pacakge, but i found that when the total length of ip package is larger that 1500, wireshark will show the length as 0 in the raw data filed.
![wireshark snapshot][wirshark snapshot]

Comment: We might be able to help you better if you could provide a screen-shot and the capture file.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably the result of [large segment offload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_segment_offload) on transmission or [large receive offload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_receive_offload) on reception; those packets probably correspond to multiple IP datagrams and multiple TCP segments on the wire.